# How to Download/Downgrade Android emulator manually

Tags: android, android-emulator

I updated Android Studio with its components last week. But I keep facing troubles with emulator. Before updating everything was fine. Now i just want to get my old emulator back. After searching I came across this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120854/how-to-downgrade-android-emulator)  .

The link to manually download is like `http://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-4266726.zip`

Answer says

> Basically, just put the # (the one in major.minor.patch-#) along with
>   darwin/windows/linux if you'd like to download any previous build.

I just don't know what to replace **4266726** with?

The version I am using right now is 29.0.9 and I want **28.0.25 (March 29, 2019 release)**

OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download 28.0.25 here:

- Windows: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-5395263.zip
- Mac: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-5395263.zip
- Linux: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux-5395263.zip

Comment: Can you explain how to get those numbers?

Comment: I got these links from SoftBank Robotics. They are providing an android emulator for their robot which does not work with the new version. So I'm sorry I cannot tell you how to get the download links for any other versions.

Comment: Seems like it is a latest version supported by El Capitan 10.11.5. The emulator being installed by Android Studio (3.3.2 in my case) says "Emulator: Sorry, "qemu-system-i386" can not be run on this version of macOS. Qt requires macOS 10.12.0 or later, you have macOS 10.11.5.". THANK YOU, GOOGLE, FOR THAT! Why the heck did you install it then? Google guys, hire more "cool" engineers like you do, so we will have more quests like this!

Comment: If you go to https://issuetracker.google.com and search for the desired version (e.g. "28.0.25"), you'll probably find issue reports which contain the build number.

Comment: @Nux, I have found version-number mapping here: https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive