# Any chance to run Android Studio Emulator on Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan?

Tags: android, macos, haxm

I've installed Android Studio 3.5 on a Mac OS X (version 10.11 El Capitan) laptop.
When I try to run "Hello World" app in the emulator, I'm running into error that reads

```
Emulator: Process finished with exit code 133 (interrupted by signal 5: SIGTRAP)
```

Additionally, an system-native error window pops up that says:

> emulator cannot be opened because of a problem.
>
> Check with the developer to make sure emulator works with this version
>   of OS X. You may need to reinstall the application. Be sure to install
>   any available updates for the application and OS X.
>
> Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to
>   Apple.

I did the default installation first. Then, after quite some googling, I've found out that HAXM version is incompatible with my OS. OK, but it's about "acceleration", so if uninstall it, then, according to uninstall script,

> ```
> Important: Removing Intel HAXM will disable acceleration of all Intel(R) x86
> Android emulators. Your Android Virtual Devices will continue to function, but
> will no longer be accelerated.
> ```

Hmm, I've got the same error after uninstalling HAXM. Then I completely removed Android Studio, and installed it again, this time unticking the HAXM box. Same error.

```
11:58   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project /Users/<user>/AndroidStudioProjects/myfirstapp

11:58   Emulator: dyld: Symbol not found: _kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom

11:58   Emulator: Referenced from: /Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5WebEngineCoreAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)

11:58   Emulator: Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

11:58   Emulator: in /Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5WebEngineCoreAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib

11:58   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 133 (interrupted by signal 5: SIGTRAP)
```

OK,

> (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)

in the log is a worrying sign. However, the [download page](https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads) states the following system requirements, all of which are met:

> ```
> Mac® OS X® 10.10 (Yosemite) or higher, up to 10.14 (macOS Mojave)
> 4 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended
> 2 GB of available disk space minimum,
> 4 GB Recommended (500 MB for IDE + 1.5 GB for Android SDK and emulator system image)
> 1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution
> ```

**EDIT: using older version**

As suggested in comments, I've tried an older version (3.0.1), as I found a reference suggesting it works on my OS. But I've run into exact the same problem. It turned out, that during the installation process the latest greatest incompatible components are downloaded and installed on the first launch without asking anything.

Is it possible to plug an older emulator in?

Has anyone run into this problem and solved it?

A couple of possibly notes:

- I'm hesitant to upgrade the OS, because I need my old Adobe CS3 products
- I do have VirtualBox installed on my laptop (some posts that I read today implied this could be relevant).
- I am a software developer, but this is my first experience with mobile apps.

Comment: It sounds like you are getting a warning not an error. Does the emulator launch? If given a long time (10-15 minutes) do you get the home screen after first time start?

Comment: @MorrisonChang: No, emulator doesn't launch. I have updated my question by including complete log messages. It looks for something and doesn't find it.

Comment: Requirements may refer to Android Studio itself, on [Intel HAXM](https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-macOS) 10.12 is stated as requirement.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: it doesn't work even without ANY accelerator installed.

Comment: You can try using some older versions https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Comment: I agree with trying the older versions of Android Studio, Apple's Xcode tools for Mac increases the min supported MacOS version with each release so if so HAXM is updated for the newest version of MacOS, backward compatibility is suspect.

Comment: I was going to suggest: https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases or dig through older version of the Intel site via archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20160131224515/https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/tools but I think you'll encounter similar issues. For those older versions of Android Studio, if you don't install HAXM and run the ARM not x86 emulator, it will run slow. At that point using a physical device is better. Trying to run Android on VirtualBox is another path. Or switch OS (Win/Linux) machines as that version of MacOS is no longer supported.

Comment: Or try the personal version of Genymotion emulator (which uses Virtualbox).

Comment: Hi @badbishop, i am also stuck with the same problem, did you got any solution.

Comment: hey @badbishop did you found any solution? i am facing the same issue

Comment: @RamshaSaeed I've managed to run emulator from CLI, but AndroidStudio doesn't recognize the fact and keeps demanding newer incompatible emulator. I've filed a bug.

Comment: thanks @badbishop for your response! i just installed Genymotion with virtual box. and its working fine.

Comment: Faced same issue. I updated my OS to 10.12 and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [download 28.0.25 version of emulator (package named "emulator-darwin-5395263").](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56079429/how-to-download-downgrade-android-emulator-manually)
this version of emulator works on my MacOS 10.11.5 and seems like its a last version supported by 'El Capitan'. Also you will maybe need some old HAXM version, 7.3.2 works for me.

Comment: what I do with download files?

Comment: Obviously you should install and use it in AS